# How can I copy installed gems from between Docker stages?

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile, rubygems, bundler

I have a `Dockerfile` which I'm trying to make multi-staged. It looks something like this:

```
FROM <image> AS build-step
RUN bundle install

FROM <image>
COPY --from=build-step $BUNDLE_INSTALL_PATH ./
```

Now I'm not sure what to use for the `BUNDLE_INSTALL_PATH`. What's the cleanest way to copy over bundle installs from one stage to another?

Comment: are you changing anything else besides the installation of the dependencies?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli nope not really. I just want to run the install in one stage and copy over the installed files in the next stage.

Comment: if so then its just seams useless unless you have hard need to use a different image in each stage or a functional benefit its just more complex as far as I see it. multi stage benefits derive from the option to not include useless extra data from build or test stages, which is not the case here

Comment: Do you want to try `volume` or `environment` in `docker-compose.yml`?   This guy shared his `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` where he seems to do something like you mentioned - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70746798/docker-compose-and-rails-console-issue-could-not-find-rake-13-0-6-in-any-of-th    See `BUNDLE_PATH` and `BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG`

Comment: "multi stage benefits derive from the option to not include useless extra data from build or test stages" I ran into this today with this use case in mind. I have to use `ruby:<version>` as my base image instead of `ruby:<version>-slim` because I need some system libraries installed in order to build native extensions for a gem. I'd like those system libraries, and all the other stuff included in the non-slim variant of the `ruby` image, to be excluded from my built image. I just need the gems, including the build binaries for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default location (likely `/usr/local/bundle`) or set it explicitly. I have done both; explicitly set the default location just to it's obvious where it's coming from.

```
FROM app_base as gems
...
# /usr/local/bundle is the default location, but make it explicit
RUN bundle config set --global path /usr/local/bundle

COPY ./Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install ... other flags for my build
...

FROM app_base as prod

...
COPY --from gems /usr/local/bundle /usr/local/bundle 
...
```

However some gems may install libraries or binaries beyond what's in the bundle; you may need to do more if these extra installed resources are required in your build.